# Plug-in to use in Microsoft Edge to highlight text in websites (like Diigo)

Tags: web-services, annotation, microsoft-edge

Is there any web service that I can use to highlight text in websites in Edge browser? I like Diigo and Annotary but they have extensions only for Chrome.

The feature I'm looking for is like painting a line in your book with a yellow highlighter. For example:

[image: example]

That's the only feature I need.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I've integrated that with your question. Could you please [edit] it again and add how it should work? E.g. should it have an addon, so when you visit the very same page again your highlights are loaded automatically?

Comment: Microsoft Edge doesn't have plugin or extension features.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [11 Tips and Tricks for Microsoft Edge on Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/222214/11-tips-and-tricks-for-microsoft-edge-on-windows-10/) on howtogeek.com, you don't need a plugin:

> Edge includes web page annotation features, which is part of why Edge is branded as a browser built for “doing.” Tap the “Make a Web Note” button — the one between the hub and the share button on the toolbar — to start marking up a web page.
>   Use the tools to draw on, highlight, erase, add notes, and copy individual parts of a web page. The Save button allows you to save the note to Microsoft OneNote, your favorites, or your reading list. You can also use the Share button to share your marked up note.

[image]

Comment: How it works is that it converts the page to an image and lets you draw or highlight anything you want However, it's very hard to highlight a line straight since you have to hold and drag your hand still in the line. If you have a look at Diigo, it's the way easier to highlight a line since it's just about selecting text, not drawing on image. I'm looking for a solution that lets me select and highlight text. Thank you for your suggestion though